# アンチキーロガーソフトの仕組みについて

Tags: c++, visual-c++

アンチキーロガーソフトの仕組みについて
アンチキーロガーソフト（有名なところでいうと「ノーロガー」https://www.vector.co.jp/soft/winnt/util/se337673.html）はどのような仕組みでキーロガーの無効化しているのでしょうか？

私自身、C++でWindowsフック（グローバルフック WH_KEYBOARD_LL）を用いたキーロガーを開発していたのですが、ノーロガーにすべて防がれてしまい、どのような仕組みで無効化しているか気になった次第です。

もしかして、WH_DEBUGでフックの前に呼び出しているのかなとか思ったのですが、キーコードを変えてしまえば正常にキー入力が出来ませんから、キーロガーのフックだけを巧みにかわしてプログラムにメッセージを送っているということになります。

以下に私のキーロガーのログファイルを記します。
Code=1とはKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT構造体のvkCodeに送られてきたキーコードです。

```
M 18:03:22 [左クリック] 
K 18:03:25 A
K 18:03:25 B
K 18:03:25 C
M 18:03:28 [左クリック] ←ノーロガー起動
K 18:03:29 [OEM固有] Code = 1
K 18:03:29 [OEM固有] Code = 1
K 18:03:29 [OEM固有] Code = 1
K 18:03:30 [OEM固有] Code = 1
K 18:03:31 [OEM固有] Code = 1
K 18:03:31 [OEM固有] Code = 1
K 18:03:32 [OEM固有] Code = 1
K 18:03:32 [OEM固有] Code = 1
K 18:03:32 [OEM固有] Code = 1
K 18:03:33 [OEM固有] Code = 1
K 18:03:33 [OEM固有] Code = 1 ←ノーロガー終了
K 18:03:37 1
K 18:03:38 2
K 18:03:38 3
M 18:03:41 [左クリック]
K 18:03:42 [L-Alt]
K 18:03:42 [F3]
K 18:03:42 [--END KEY LOGGER--]
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11206405426

Comment: マルチポスト　https://dixq.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=20602